# Password change through script

Tags: bash, shell, github, expect

I am writing a bash script which will login on storage box through ssh and will execute admin user password change command.

How can I write a bash script which will reply automatically of below 2 question during the script execution password change command execute?

I mean when storage box OS asks below 2 question then password [ which is stored in one variable] should be automatically given by script one by one both time.

```
Enter a new password:
Enter it again:
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, it's quite unclear what you want to ask and you might want to look at the "how-to-ask-a-question" page (link: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you provide a minimal example of what you are trying to achieve would be a good starting point. Thanks,

Comment: Check my edited version again

Answer (score 0):

You need an expect script to hand values over.
The "language" consists of three import features:

> - spawn:
>     Starting a script or a program.
> - expect:
>     Waiting for program output.
> - send:
>     Sending a reply to your program.

You would for example expect the phrase: "*Enter a new password:*"
And then would send your variable "*$PASSWORD*"

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Enter your username: ' username
read -sp 'Enter a new password: ' passinput
read -sp 'Enter it again: ' passval
echo

echo "Changing password for $username ...."

if [ $passinput != $passval ]
then
    echo "Password and password validation does not match"
else
    ssh root@$server "passwd --stdin renu <<EOF
    $userinput
    $passinput
    EOF";
    echo "Thanks $uservar we have updated your login details"
fi
```